# Yii Shell history using up and down arrows

Tags: shell, command-line, yii, history

I searched quite a bit for something telling how to enable history for the Yii shell but I couldn't find anything. When developing in Ruby on Rails I often use the console which keeps history after the addition of a [script](http://www.enriquedelgado.com/articles/2007/04/25/interactive-ruby-console-tip-remember-the-last-x-commands-even-after-logging-out) someone put together. I'm now spoiled and I need this in Yii! If it doesn't exist I am willing to attempt to create it myself but I thought I would ask first since I'm new to Yii.

Comment: What do you mean "for the Yii shell"? `yiic` is executed from the OS shell, which presumably already keeps history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for quite a while.  I found nothing.  The answer seems to be: create it yourself.  Sorry guy.